# Where are the files stored during Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I was trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to Ubuntu 16.04LTS, however there was some issue with my internet connection and the software update tool had to abort the download. Now, I have changed my mind and want to wait for some more time before I attempt the upgrade. I wanted to cleanup the files/packages that were downloaded during the unsuccessful attempt. Could someone please guide me where does Ubuntu store those files/packages?